# Does Linq provide a way to easily spot gaps in a sequence?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, sequences

I am managing a directory of files.  Each file will be named similarly to `Image_000000.png`, with the numeric portion being incremented for each file that is stored.

Files can also be deleted, leaving gaps in the number sequence.  The reason I am asking is because I recognize that at some point in the future, the user could use up the number sequence unless I takes steps to reuse numbers when they become available.  I realize that it is a million, and that's a lot, but we have 20-plus year users, so "someday" is not out of the question.

So, I am specifically asking whether or not there exists a way to easily determine the gaps in the sequence without simply looping.  I realize that because it's a fixed range, I could simply loop over the expected range.

And I will unless there is a better/cleaner/easier/faster alternative.  If so, I'd like to know about it.

This method is called to obtain the next available file name:

```
public static String GetNextImageFileName()
{
    String retFile = null;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(userVars.ImageDirectory);
    FileInfo[] fia = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    String lastFile = fia.Where(i => i.Name.StartsWith("Image_") && i.Name.Substring(6, 6).ContainsOnlyDigits()).OrderBy(i => i.Name).Last().Name;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastFile))
    {
        Int32 num;
        String strNum = lastFile.Substring(6, 6);
        String strExt = lastFile.Substring(13);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strNum) && 
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(strExt) && 
            strNum.ContainsOnlyDigits() &&
            Int32.TryParse(strNum, out num))
        {
            num++;
            retFile = String.Format("Image_{0:D6}.{1}", num, strExt);
            while (num <= 999999 && File.Exists(retFile))
            {
                num++;
                retFile = String.Format("Image_{0:D6}.{1}", num, strExt);
            }
        }
    }

    return retFile;
}
```

**EDIT:  in case it helps anyone, here is the final method, incorporating Daniel Hilgarth's answer:**

```
public static String GetNextImageFileName()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(userVars.ImageDirectory);
    FileInfo[] fia = di.GetFiles("Image_*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    List<Int32> fileNums = new List<Int32>();
    foreach (FileInfo fi in fia)
    {
        Int32 i;
        if (Int32.TryParse(fi.Name.Substring(6, 6), out i))
            fileNums.Add(i);
    }
    var result = fileNums.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                .Where(x => x.Index != x.Value)
                .Select(x => (Int32?)x.Index)
                .FirstOrDefault();

    Int32 index;
    if (result == null)
        index = fileNums.Count - 1;
    else
        index = result.Value - 1;

    var nextNumber = fileNums[index] + 1;

    if (nextNumber >= 0 && nextNumber <= 999999)
        return String.Format("Image_{0:D6}", result.Value);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the numbers to increment, or do you just need unique filenames?  There are easier ways of getting unique filenames than what you're using.

Comment: @Servy Would you mean something like `Path.GetTempFileName()`?  I considered that option, but I have a requirement to ensure that the user could find the file outside our application if necessary, so I went with something more readable by "average Joe".

Comment: Just stick a date in `yymmdd` format at the front. If you also append the 6 digit number to the date, you can just wrap the number when you get to 999999. It won't give you any collisions unless you create more than 999999 files in one day. (It will give you problems in 2099, but you might not be too worried about that... ;)

Comment: That was actually exactly what I was thinking, but even if you do want something a bit more readable you have better options.  For example, append the created timestamp to the end of the question (just be sure to have enough precision that there still aren't dupes and handle the case of dups due to daylight savings (possibly by using a locality without DST)).  There are other options besides those as well that would still be easier to handle than what you have, my question remains, are they an option, or is it imperative that you use this system?

Comment: @Servy No, not imperative.  Of my invention to satisfy the requirements of uniquely named, identifiable, and in one folder.

Comment: @Servy To take it a bit further, the reason I avoided the date/time issue is that the usage here is such that the user is likely to dump a slug of images in all in one browse and not again.  Therefore, they'd all be the same date, for one, and likely the same minute.  That would make them tough for the average user to pick out of a folder, I think.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I've been considering your thought, Matthew.  It's a good one, I'll hang onto that idea.  You'll see in my comment to Servy that I avoided date/time intentionally, but yours is a reasonable take on a compromise.

Comment: Is 10,000,000 files still not out of the question? Or 100,000,000? In other words: Just increase the number of digits you are using until you can be sure that there won't be a wrap-around.

Comment: @DonBoitnott That's why I mention precision.  You simply need to include enough precision in your date/time to not have dups.  That may mean going down to the second, or even to the millisecond.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I wish I knew for sure, but that's basically predicting the future.  Honestly, I expect that the one million I have chosen is enough, and I even considered not worrying about the number reuse issue at all.  But out of an abundance of caution, I am at least considering my options for what caring about it means.

Comment: My pragmatic approach would be the following: If you think that this actually should not happen, just throw a descriptive error message if the user used up all the numbers. You could even add a help topic about it which basically would say: Move the existing files to a new folder and reset counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach to find the first number of the first gap would be the following:

```
int[] existingNumbers = /* extract all numbers from all filenames and order them */
var allNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000);
var result = allNumbers.Where(x => !existingNumbers.Contains(x)).First();
```

This will return 1,000,000 if all numbers have been used and no gaps exist.

This approach has the drawback that it performs rather badly, as it iterates `existingNumbers` multiple times.

A somewhat better approach would be to use Zip:

```
allNumbers.Zip(existingNumbers, (a, e) => new { Number = a, ExistingNumber = e })
          .Where(x => x.Number != x.ExistingNumber)
          .Select(x => x.Number)
          .First();
```

An improved version of DuckMaestro's answer that actually returns the first value of the first gap - and not the first value *after* the first gap - would look like this:

```
var tmp = existingNumbers.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                         .Where(x => x.Index != x.Value)
                         .Select(x => (int?)x.Index)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

int index;
if(tmp == null)
    index = existingNumbers.Length - 1;
else
    index = tmp.Value - 1;

var nextNumber = existingNumbers[index] + 1;
```

Comment: I see that `Zip` is a later introduction (.NET 4.0, I think?).  Unfortunately, this app is stuck in .NET 3.5 for the near term.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: Indeed, it has been introduced in .NET 4. You can create it yourself by means of enumerators. But I think you simply should use the solution proposed by [DuckMaestro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17432454/572644).

Comment: I'm not sure about the last edits, but overall, I think the two of you have provided me with a very good solution.  See my latest OP edit for what I _think_ will be the final code modification. BTW... `tmp` is returning the value that _is the gap_, not before or after.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: In my version, it returns the first value of the gap and at the same time the *index* of the first value *after* the first gap. The additional code with the `if` afterwards accounts for the case when there is no gap. Your final edit doesn't account for that case and therefore doesn't even compile.

Comment: Doesn't compile?  Sure it does.  I do see your point about the necessity of that last bit, however.  When there is no gap, `null` is returned.  Therefore, you need that additional check to get the next number.  I then validate `nextNumber` to be `<= 999999` to maintain the range I am looking for.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: "Doesn't compile" was meant with regards to the code in your question. It certainly doesn't compile. It misses a return in case the `if` condition is not satisfied.

Comment: BTW: `if (Enumerable.Range(0, 999999).Contains(nextNumber))` is a really, really inefficient way to say `if(nextNumber >= 0 && nextNumber <= 999999)`.

Comment: Now I see it...bad copy/paste.  There was supposed to be a `return null;` at the end.  Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that .Zip example will throw an exception if there are no gaps. Additionally, I have had better luck with the .Except method like @It'sNotALie suggested.

Comment: @JasonWilliams: Changing `First` to `FirstOrDefault` will remove the exception. A `null` check will tell you if it found a gap or not. If you think the solution with `Except` is better, please be so kind and post your own answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth you're right, I should have posted my own answer. My apologies.
However, .FirstOrDefault() will actually yield zero; not null. So, if your sequence needs to contain zero, you won't be able to tell if the gap is "real" or not.

Comment: @JasonWilliams: Indeed, we are talking about numbers here, good catch. In that case, `FirstOrDefault` really isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Improving over the other answer, use the alternate version of `Where`.

```
int[] existingNumbers = ...
var result = existingNumbers.Where( (x,i) => x != i ).FirstOrDefault();
```

The value `i` is a counter starting at `0`.

This version of `where` is supported in .NET 3.5 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Could you please explain why this is an improvement?  I am not a Linq expert.  And are suggesting that I would wrap a `for` loop over `i` around this?

Comment: @DonBoitnott: As you can see, `i` is one of the parameters of the lambda you pass to `Where`. It will be the index of the current item and is passed to your lambda by LINQ. No `for` loop here. Go read the LINQ if that still wasn't clear :) And it is an improvement over my answers because it iterates only *one* collection only as far as needed. It won't get better than that - I would use this approach in my code instead of the ones I suggested.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth So what is the end value here, then?  Yours had a fixed range (0, 1000000), but this appears to loop over just what is in `existingNumbers`.  So I will get the first gap value, or the next available value, or...?  What?

Comment: @DonBoitnott: Good question. It will give you the first value *after* the gap, which I realize is not really helpful. To actually get the first number of the gap, you would need to do more something like this: `var index = existingNumbers.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x }).Where(x => x.Index != x.Value).Select(x => x.Index).FirstOrDefault() - 1; if(index == -1) index = existingNumbers.Length - 1; var nextNumber = existingNumbers[index] + 1;`

Comment: @DonBoitnott: I updated my answer to contain code similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstnonexistingfile = Enumerable.Range(0,999999)
  .Select(x => String.Format("Image_{0:D6}.{1}", x, strExt))
  .FirstOrDefault(x => !File.Exists(x));
```

This will iterate from `0` to `999999`, then output the result of the `String.Format()` as an `IEnumerable<string>` and then find the first string out of that sequence that returns false for `File.Exists()`.

Comment: I tried this and it returned the first file that _does exist_.  The files in my directory were between `Image_000000.png` and `Image_000038.png`.  The only gap was `Image_000007`, but I got back `Image_000000.png`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but it has been suggested (in the comments) that you could use `.Except()` instead. I tend to like this solution a little better since it will give you the first missing number (the gap) or the next smallest number in the sequence. Here's an example:

```
var allNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 999999); //999999 is arbitrary. You could use int.MaxValue, but it would degrade performance
var existingNumbers = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };

int result;
var missingNumbers = allNumbers.Except(existingNumbers);
if (missingNumbers.Any())
  result = missingNumbers.First();
else //no missing numbers -- you've reached the max
  result = -1;
```

Running the above code would set `result` to:

```
3
```

Additionally, if you changed existingNumbers to:

```
var existingNumbers = new int[] { 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6 };
```

So there isn't a gap, you would get 7 back.

Anyway, that's why I prefer Except over the Zip solution -- just my two cents.
Thanks!

Comment: This has the disadvantage that it enumerates `missingNumbers` twice (at least up to the first gap) and thus executes the `Except` twice. A solution without this problem would look like this: `var missingNumbers = allNumbers.Except(existingNumbers).GetEnumerator();
if (missingNumbers.MoveNext())
  result = missingNumbers.Current;
else //no missing numbers -- you've reached the max
  result = -1;`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth so the performance issue (enumerating twice) is due to calling the .Any() method?

Comment: It is due to calling two methods on `missingNumbers` that both iterate the query. Remember: LINQ is implemented using deferred execution